# C# GetFontSize Function

Tags: c#, fonts, font-size

I'm currently working on an online game server, i've started coding it today with using C#. Since i don't know a lot of things about C#, i get the color but i can't get the font size tho.

I did it like this :

```
public static string GetColor(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}CB-{1},{2},{3},{4}{5}", "{", r, g, b, a, "}");
    }
```

And

```
_commandDescriptions.Add("broadcast", HelperUtils.GetColor(255, 255, 0, 255) + "/broadcast <message>");
```

So, how can i get the font size by its codes. ( Like F_2002_15 ) . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us some context. What exactly do you want to know the size of?

Comment: You should update your question, specify what platform you're on (WinForms I guess ?) and clearly explain because it is currently unclear.

Comment: Nope. They're class lib. ( .dll ) . Would this work ? : `public static string GetFontSize(int f, int z = 2002, int o = 15)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}F_{1},{2}", "{", f, z, o, "}");
        }`

Comment: Way too unclear. "F_2002_15" does not look like any font name or size I've ever seen... Also please try to name variables with words instead of letters for code you want others to see/understand (If you don't people do read/understand particular piece it may be better not to post it at all in the question).

Answer (score 0):

- If you have a real `Font F` you get its size as `F.Size` or `F.SizeInPoints`.
- If you want to extract the trailing 15 form your string F_2002_15 you can do it like this:

  string fontname = "F_2002_15";
  int fontsize = Convert.ToInt32(fontname.Substring(fontname.LastIndexOf('_')+1));
- otherwise you will have to explain more clearly what you want